# Help choose a better upgrade for my MacBook5,2

Tags: upgrade

I recently got a 2009 macbook 5,2 as a gift from my uncle. When I tried to install MAMP it says i need to upgrade my OS.

What will be best option for my mac.

I am very new to these mac things & I like it so much.

Configuration:

Model Name: MacBook

Model Identifier:   MacBook5,2

Processor Name: Intel Core 2 Duo

Processor Speed:    2.13 GHz

Memory 2 GB

I am not sure is it enough to suggest an option, so please don't hesitate to contact me if you need more info.

I found [this](https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-2465) article in Apple Support forums.

But its not cleared my doubt.
Can anyone make a detailed answer for this?

like

- how to get directly update to more newer OS?
- how to get the    installation disk? can i get it free?
- do i really need to purchase    one?
- Will a used disk work with my etc?

Comment: If you hold down the option key and click on the Apple menu at upper left, you can choose System Profiler.  Once that has opened, look in the Memory section to see what you have installed.  Apple currently only sells their most recent OS release, Mountain Lion (aka OS X 10.8), but depending on your installed memory you might not be able to use it.

Comment: Installed memory is 2GB.

Comment: @da4, can i expect a more detailed answer?

Comment: Based on the specs you gave, Mac OS X 10.7 aka Lion is the most recent version of [OS X](http://www.apple.com/osx/specs/) that you'll be able to install onto that version MacBook (Early 2008, from what I can tell).  If you contact your local Apple Store you should be able to purchase Lion, as I don't think it's available through the Mac App Store anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snow Leopard, Lion or Mountain Lion.  As da4 mentioned, you will need to find out the capabilities of your machine and look up the requirements of the operating systems I listed.

Comment: Thanks, i am planning to use lion. is this the best option as my mac is pretty old? Or i choose some leopard i really dont want to loose the performance.

Comment: That model MacBook is [not supported by Mountain Lion](http://www.apple.com/osx/specs/).

Answer (score 1):

You could do what I did to my macbook which is install a solid state drive and 4gb of ram and get mac os sierra patch tool and download mac os sierra it runs great on my computer with no issues it was definitely worth it.